# Wordpress MailChimp Framework suddenly stopped working without modification

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I had a WordPress webshop setup, and I am using the [MailChimp Framework plugin][1] for sending newsletter, among other things. Now, the setup has been running since January 1st, then all of the sudden the Mailchimp framework suddenly stopped sending. The "Everything's Chimpy" ping status does not appear as well, sometimes it's NULL, sometimes it's garbage character. I am pretty sure I haven't touched any code of the plugin, and a colleague having a totally different project has experienced it as well.

Also, I remember their reply used to be "text/json", but now I see a reply with Content-type "application/json".

Is any one of you experiencing this as well?

Update: Mailchimp API responded:

http://groups.google.com/group/mailchimp-api-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f46b9ddfc6725aa3

http://groups.google.com/group/mailchimp-api-discuss/browse_thread/thread/8a03c3a9cd3dc3bf

There seems to be a problem with connections being suddenly being dropped at mid-call. They have updated the MCAPI wrapper. I haven't tested this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the author of Wordpress MailChimp Framework is on indefinite vacation. So I suggest to you having the same problem as this one is to go through the PHP MCAPI wrapper (http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/downloads/#php) since this one is directly supported by the MailChimp team. The team has updated the wrapper to handle dropped connections.

And yeah, forget about the Wordpress MailChimp Framework if you want your sanity.